# Mixing sound with text on movie.py

Tags: python-3.x, moviepy

Trying to get something basic to work on movie.py Just want to display some text and play some music.
The text displays but the music does not
Here is my code

```
from moviepy.editor import *
audio=AudioFileClip("music/above-the-clouds.mp3")
txt_clip=TextClip("rock around the clock",fontsize=70,color='white')
txt_clip=txt_clip.set_pos('center').set_duration(300)
txt_clip.fps=24
txt_clip.set_audio(audio.volumex(4))
txt_clip.write_videofile("merged.mp4")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line

```
txt_clip.set_audio(audio.volumex(4))
```

to

```
txt_clip = txt_clip.set_audio(audio.volumex(4))
```